# Using Dot Product with InterpolatingFunctions

Tags: differential-equations, linear-algebra

I am using NDSolve on a vector function $\mathbf y'(x)=f[\mathbf y(x)]$ with initial condition $\mathbf y_0$, where the dimension of the vector should be user-defined.

```
Clear[y, y0]
y0 = {1, 2}
sol = NDSolve[{y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == y0}, {y}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

I'm attempting to use the resulting InterpolatingFunction as an input into a matrix ODE, $\mathbf z'(x) = g[\mathbf z(x)]$, with initial condition $\mathbf z_0$.

```
Clear[z,z0]
z0 = {{1., 2.},{3.,4.}}
failing = NDSolve[{z'[x] + foo[y[x] /. sol, {1, 1}] z[x] == 0, z[0] == z0}, {z}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Where

```
foo[vectx_?(VectorQ[#] &), vecty_?(VectorQ[#] &)] := vectx.vecty
```

The function `foo[x,y]` is failing to compute the dot product correctly because the dimensions don't match up (`Length[y[x] /. sol,]` is `1`), although `VectorQ[y[x] /. sol]` yields `True`.  Naively, I expected that the result of `NDSolve` would be something like

$\mathbf y(x) = (\text{InterpolatingFunction}[y_1(x)], \text{InterpolatingFunction}[y_2(x)],...)$

So that the dot product

$\mathbf y \cdot (a,b,...)=a \, \text{InterpolatingFunction}[y_1(x)] + b \, \text{InterpolatingFunction}[y_2(x)]+...$

Rather, it's something more like `{InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>][t]}`, which is trivially a vector since it's enclosed by `{...}`.

How do I express my "dot product" logic above in Mathematica-ese?  Or is there a more elegant way to get the code flow that I want?

Comment: You can change `sol = NDSolve...` to `sol = First@NDSolve..` to get `y[x]/.sol` to have the form `InterpolatingFunction[...]` instead of `{InterpolatingFunction[...]}`

Comment: The `(VectorQ[#] &)` is not needed, `VectorQ` will do the job in this case.

Comment: Alternatively `(VectorQ[#, NumericQ]&)` is more precise.  (Note that `VectorQ[y[x] /. sol]` is `True`, but `VectorQ[y[0.4] /. sol]` is `False`.)  One could also add a condition, `foo[..] /; Length[vectx] == Length[vecty] := ..`, but that's not really necessary.  The major problem has been pointed out by ssch and partial81.

Comment: @ssch, this worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following could help:

Use in your code

```
failing = NDSolve[{z'[x] + 
foo[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol][[1]], {1, 1}] z[x] == 0, z[0] == z0}, {z}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Please tell me if this works for you.

Btw. You can also skip the `Evaluate` and use only `foo[y[x] /. sol[[1]], {1, 1}]`. The result is the same.

Comment: This works, cheers!

Comment: Great to hear! Btw. `First[expr]` (as ssch writes) and `expr[[1]]`, are equivalent. So, chose the notation you like more ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You asked if there's a more elegant way to achieve your output. I think the simplest approach is to combine your 2 ODEs into a single ODE, something like:

```
y0 = {1, 2};
z0 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

{ysol, zsol} = NDSolveValue[
    {
    y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == y0,
    z'[x] + y[x].{1,1} z[x] == 0, z[0] == z0
    },
    {y, z},
    {x, 0, 10}
];
```

Note that I used [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) instead of [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve), and just used [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) instead of your auxiliary function `foo`.

Visualization:

```
Plot[zsol[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]